# How will i execute facebook ajax link using PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

how can i execute facebook ajax link like `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/bookmark/groups/leave/?group_id=XXXXXXX` (which can only be executed using a mouse click) using PHP. So far i can get all my groups ID via the graph api. Found this outdated code on google: http://bpaste.net/show/76918/

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i know only how to get all my groups id. If i know how to process the ajax link, i can loop and execute my function.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it via Facebook API, instead of mocking AJAX request

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));
$feed = $facebook->api('YOUR_GRAPH_API_CALL');
```

Comment: yes i've used facebook php api and as i've already mentioned i can successfully retrieve my groups id using php sdk. but my main question is to execute the facebook ajax link in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you can use graph api in facebook developper space :

check this and replace your-id by your id:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=you-id%3Ffields%3Dgroups.fields%28id%29